# Working with Korean characters in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am attempting to make a Korean version of my app using eclipse. If I cut and paste the Korean text into eclipse's view of my strings.xml all the characters appear as little squares. But when I change to the Graphical view of my layouts, the Korean characters are displayed correctly... I could limp along in this way and get the program made, but would be much happier if I could see the characters appear properly when looking at strings.xml. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing your text encoding in your editor to `UTF-8.`

Right click --> properties -->resources -->text file encoding.

Comment: Thanks, but what happens when you right click varies enormously depending on what's being displayed and where the cursor is... can you express your answer to remove this ambiguity.

Comment: Sorry about this. You can click on individual file for this and also folder or project in eclipse. But first try on your strings.xml.

Comment: If I right click on the text of strings.xml a menu appears with the word properties on it - but if I click that all that happens is a new tab appear in the window underneath my text with two sections - Property and Value. In the Property column, there is the word Attributes and underneath that is the word "name". In the value column it has the word "Loading" - there does not appear to be anything labelled "resources" for me to select.

Comment: Clicking on the "project" menu at the top of the eclipse window brought me to a different dead end.

Comment: Doing a right click on the name of the strings.xml file finally brought me to a dialog which allowed me to set text file encoding to utf-8... but after it was selected there was no difference - still showing little rectangles.

Comment: After changing to UTF-8 trying copy strings again to strings.xml.

Comment: when u copy korean string in your os editor like notepad, do they still show up as rectangle? Also read this link http://support.dtsearch.com/dts0140.htm under Background-->font.

Comment: "when u copy korean string in your os editor like notepad, do they still show up as rectangle?" - oops! no... that could be the problem. I'll fix it.